# parallel execution of Vagrant result in random connection losts

Tags: windows, vagrant

We have a set of scripts around vagrant that creates machines with our product on AWS.

To test these scripts and the different options we support we have a Perl script that creates and runs a big list of machines and tests them.
This is executed nightly, and can create up to 85 machines for tests.
Right now it’s doing up for all machines, then tests for all and destroys all.

But we have a problem where we get fewmachines stuck in up and sometimes in provision.
They can be stuck in random parts of the process.
Every time we get different machines  stuck, and when you try manually to run them, they work fine.

We can see ruby process stuck on 50% CPU and a very slow, and killing it frees the rest of the machines a bit.
If you try running just one of those machines to start by hand, it works.

When we tried lower number of machines, still some had this issue.
We tried moving from win2012 to 2008, same.
CPU is in high usage, but not so much on memory or network.

We tried playing with delays, and number of parallel running vms, trying to get around this.
But I rather figure out what is the bottleneck, and fix it to move on.

The only clue I have is the vagrant global-status command which shows me a lot of machines in preparing state that no longer exist.
And the latest stuck targets are there at the bottom.

We still work with vagrant 1.7.4
With the below plugins:

- winrm-fs (0.2.2)
- Version Constraint: 0.2.2 vagrant-aws (0.6.0)
- Version Constraint: 0.6.0 vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1)
- Version Constraint: 1.4.1 vagrant-serverspec (1.1.0)
- Version Constraint: 1.1.0 vagrant-share (1.1.5, system) vagrant-winrm-syncedfolders (1.0.0)
- Version Constraint: 1.0.0

What could be halting vagrant and its ruby-interpreter process?
Can it be Amazon blocking some traffic? or Windows limitations?

Comment: `vagrant global-status` is based on a cache so you can still see machines in preparing state while they will not be, until the completion/deletion of the machine completes and updates the cache

Comment: Yes , we figure that , and we will use it to catch suspended runs to re-run them